# Bulma dropdown disappears with Vue router

Tags: css, vue-router, bulma

Dropdown is working perfectly on normal pages.

But when I use Vue-router, which works like a SPA, the dropdown disappears between the navbar-item and its child navbar-link unless I move the cursor down very fast.

There are no gaps or margins in the html on the router page or between the router view and the nav. On normal web pages the transition between navbar-item to the dropdown menu is seamless. But on the router page, the dropdown disappears once the cursor moves off the inner tag which is boxed inside the outer div.

```
// outer tag
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    // inner tag
    <a class="navbar-link">More:</a>
</div>
```

setting a style="height: 100%" does not work to make the a tag fit fully inside the outer div

https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/

Comment: You have a typo in your code. There is a colon after is-hoverable instead of a quotation mark.

Comment: Correct, was just a typo in the example code. Meant to press "

Comment: ok, could you add snippet with reproduction of this bug? I don't think it's problem with vue-router, rather with styles or something, but I have too few data to give a good answer. You can play with `top` value of navbar-dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding a line break `<br>` above the columns that had a child of vue-router.

Never over-complicate the simplicity of vue or bulma!

Comment: What did you add above the columns?

Comment: Hi @Ralf, not sure what happened to this answer. I think I added a margin: 0 or z-index or both !